# How Does Kirchoff's Law Make Sense

Tags: current, basic, electrical, kirchhoffs-laws

I understand the algebra, and I can also use Kirchoff's Law in calculation.

But I struggle to understand how it makes sense logically.

The law states, that the sum of the currents entering a junction must also be the same sum for the currents leaving that junction.

Now, this would make sense in a circuit without resistors, but if I am to apply resistors, the current would be slowed, and therefore, the amount of coulombs passing through per second (amps) would be lowered, and the current on the other side would surely be lower, than before the resistor?

How does this make sense with Kirchhoff's current law?

Comment: Current is electrons. Do you think electrons are turning into heat?

Comment: *but if I am to apply resistors, some of the current will be transformed into heat energy* Uhm, **Nope**. **Current** is the amount of electrons passing per second. So you're saying that electrons are turned into heat? Are electrons "escaping" or converted into heat? Does that make sense?

Comment: Back to the old water analogy-  Suppose you have water doing work by flowing over a paddle wheel.  The amount of water flowing before and after the paddle wheel is exactly the same, yet the paddle wheel is turning and doing useful work.

Comment: Wait, perhaps I was thinking of the current's ability to do work?

So, the amount of electrons stays the same, but their electrical charge declines with a resistor, and therefore the current is technically the same before and after the resistor?

But then again, do the resistors not limit the flow of electrons going through them?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, That looks like an answer, even if it is not an especially polite one.

Comment: @JohnD right, but current is measured in ampere is c/s right?

If we pick a point in the river after the paddle wheel, surely the amount of water passing/s is lower than before the paddle wheel, due to the water having to spend time passing over the wheel, rather than straight down the river?

Comment: @GeorgeWTrump, Re, "their electrical charge declines with a resistor." No. Sticking with that water-over-the-wheel analogy, after the water has gone over the wheel, it's still the same amount of water, and its weight (the weight of the water is what turns the wheel) has not changed either. But the water now is closer to the Earth's center of gravity. Being closer to the Earth's center of gravity means that the water now has less potential energy. Electrons still have the same charge after the resistor as before, but they are closer (in Voltage) to the negative terminal of the power supply.

Comment: @GeorgeWTrump if all the water in the river passes over the paddle wheel, then it limits the "current" just as a resistor does, and the water entering=water leaving=water downstream.  If some water flows around the wheel then Kirchoff's river theorem still applies. But you can't take the water analogy TOO far, it just helps with some of the concepts.

Comment: *do the resistors not limit the flow of electrons going through them?* They do but no electrons "get lost", all the electrons that go in must come out at the other side. That means that the **current** stays the same.

Comment: @JohnD Alright, I will try to explain what I mean then.

I understand, that the same amount of coulombs on the begining side of the resistor will eventually flow over to the other side of the resistance, as long as voltage is applied.

What I can't understand is, surely the resistor will limit the flow of coulombs, making the travel from the start-end of the circuit longer, meaning less coulombs pass the point at the end of the resistance per second. I.e the current has been lowered.

But, apparently Kirchhoff's law says the opposite, that the speed of the flow will be the same.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I understand, but current is ampere right? And amp is c/s. Therefore, if the coulombs move slower, there will be fewer c per s at a given point.

If the flow of electrons is limited, fewer electrons can pass through the resistor at the same time, and therefore it will take longer.

More time per coulomb = less coulombs per second.
- or atleast, this is where I believe I must have misunderstood something.

Comment: Yes but your question was about KCL. The KCL doesn't care how fast/slow the electrons are moving, it applies to any situation even when the electrons are not moving at all (current = zero). Your misconception was that not all electrons would end up in the node where we apply the KCL. But all the electrons do end up there.

Comment: @GeorgeWTrump Mechanical analogies don't hold up 100% because this is not mechanical. Electrons are relativistic and so is the electrical wave carrying the energy (which is what we are really interested in). Recall the electron drift speed where their average speed down the wire anywhere near as fast as the wave. So even saying current = electrons is a bit of a misnomer.

Comment: Kirchoff's law makes as much sense as water flowing in garden hose. No matter in what way you split the hose into multiple sections, and at what rate the water flows through different sections, you always get out the same amount of water than you put in.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie but then it doesn't make sense to say, that the sum of the current must be the same, because current is a meassure of velocity?

Would it be accurate, if I just remembered the KCL as "The amount of coulombs passing through the start of a junction, will eventually, be the same amount passing through the end of a junction?"

Comment: KCL is basically just saying that you can't destroy electrons (at least without a nuclear reactor), so electrons in = electrons out. Conservation of energy is something else.

Comment: Re, "...because current is a meassure of velocity?" No. It's a measure of _quantity_. When we measure current, the measurement is proportional to the _number_ of electrons per second.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I think I understand the difference now, and also, you have clarified a lot of misconceptions I had before. Thank you :)

Comment: No electron left behind! | No current left behind! | No charge left behind! | Slower, can be. Fewer, can be. Different, no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current is the amount of electric charge passing through a cross-sectional area per unit time. A voltage can be thought of (but isn't!) a force. Electric charge is carried by electrons. Voltage provides an energy differential to cause the electrons to move in one direction overall.

With that picture, we can now see that what is being converted into work isn't the electrons, it is the energy potential given to it by the voltage that results in the electron flow to occur. Electrons are a conserved physical quantity, thus what enters a junction must be equally conserved by what exists a junction.

What is being converted to heat is the potential, the voltage. Hence why electrons are not converted to heat, still exist in equal number, and exit the nodes in the same quantity. However, you do get a voltage drop by the resistance.

To give a mechanical interpretation. If you roll a big rock up a hill and then push it down the hill toward a wall. The wall will provide resistance, the rock will push through the wall and lose energy in the process, but the rock is still a rock, same physical quantity, same physical properties...etc. What has changed is the energy potential given by some outside entity (you pushing it up the hill) was converted to heat and kinetic energy. The rock wasn't converted to heat energy, it remains a rock, the energy potential given to it was. Now, if you rolled multiple rocks down a hill one after the other, despite that resistance and energy loss that occurred, the rocks behind it haven't experienced this loss and will push the first rock forward, and the one behind that rock will have itself pushed forward...etc. Since current is a connected chain of such rocks, your flow over the entry and exit will be equal. What comes in must come out. You simply must keep presenting an energy differential to keep propelling them forward (voltage or gravity in the rock example).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a resistor will slow down the rate of current flow (for a given potential).  But that will cause a "traffic backup" which will also slow the rate of current flow into or out of any junction feeding that resistor to that same slow rate. Basically, in steady state, electrons can't "bunch up", because the increased charge concentration will repel them away from the traffic jam location.

And electrons don't "fly away" due to heating unless the resistor is an emitter, such as the heated filament in a vacuum tube, with an attractive charged anode nearby.

Comment: This is why the water analogies break down: water needs to be in contact with other water to apply pressure to equalize its distribution. As soon as you lose contact via voids, you lose equal distribution which means you can have uneven local rates. Electrons don't have this issue due to charge repulsion.

Comment: Wait, so the current will be the same on either side of the resistor, and therefore the sum of the beginning of the resistor will be a "slowered" version compared to before adding the resistor, and therefore the sum at the end of the resistor will also be a "slowered" version, so that they match?

I think I am beginning to understand. My logic of thought was that, if the pre-resistor current is fast, and the after-resistor current is slow, the sum of those two would be different, so that the pre-resistor current would be higher.

Comment: @GeorgeWTrump Instead of slowered/fast which carries false mechanical connotations that couple flow rate with energy, think more or less energy before and after the resistor.

Comment: @DKNguyen so... Coulomb is a measure of charge, and not particles?

But wouldn't it still mean, that there will pass less energy through a certain point after the resistor than before the resistor, unless the amount of energy moving through the whole circuit is lowered to balance out this effect?

Comment: @GeorgeWTrump This is going to sound weird, but an electron's charge does not represent how much energy it carries Yes, energy will be less after the resistor, but not charge. An electron's charge doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

if the sum of electrons entering a node is not longterm zero, then eventually there will be arcing.

Does your phone arc, even if you leave it on?